# continuously propagate event up chain

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have nested children that I want to propagate an event all the way up to the root component, is there any simple way to pass on the event?

i.e.

```
<root @custom_event="doSomething" @another_event="doSomethingElse">
    <child1 @custom_event="passItAlong" @another_event="passItAlong">
        <child2 @custom_event="passItAlong" @another_event="passItAlong">
             <child3 @click="$emit('custom_event', 'data')">
             </child3>
        </child2>
    </child1>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options here:

1. You can use `this.$root.$emit` and then event will be sent to all components at once, you can listen to it as `this.$root.$on`
2. You can create `eventBus` as explained [here](https://gist.github.com/JonasDoebertin/e87cb10df9393c3fb4c99731191cad23) and then use it wherever you need to:

```js
// The most basic event bus

// Imprt vue.js
import Vue from 'vue';

// Create empty vue.js instance to use as event bus
const Bus = new Vue({});

// Export event bus instance
export default Bus;
```

```js
// Using the most basic event bus

import Vue from 'vue';
import Bus from './basic';

Vue.component('my-first-component', {
  methods: {
    sampleClickAction() {
       Bus.$emit('my-sample-event');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('my-second-component', {
  created() {
    Bus.$on('my-sample-event', () => {
      // Do something…
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: i probably oversimplified. What if I don't want to pollute the global space. Say the "root" was actually just a parent component.

Comment: If root was just a parent then just `$emit` will work  
If you don't want to pollute global space - create special event bus  
Also, if you want to pass it to grandparent - then sometimes 2-3 levels of passing is okay.